# use redis-cli to create redis-cluster at docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, redis-cluster

i try to use one compose file to startup a reids cluster, but when i use redis-cli to create the cluster, and i must type 'yes' to agree the configuration of the cluster that command 'redis-cli --cluster create' make, so what should i deal with the compose file?

the part of compose file:

```
  redis-cli:
    images: redis:5.0.1-apline
    depends_on:
      - redis1
      - redis2
      - redis3
      - redis4
      - redis5
      - redis6
    links:
      - redis1
      - redis2
      - redis3
      - redis4
      - redis5
      - redis6
    entrypoint:
      - redis-cli
      - --cluster
      - create
      - redis1:${client_port}
      - redis2:${client_port}
      - redis3:${client_port}
      - redis4:${client_port}
      - redis5:${client_port}
      - redis6:${client_port}
      - --cluster-replicas
      - '1'
      - -a
      - ${client_pwd}
```

[and the pic of logs after compose up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yF2PE.png)

Comment: Dont use pictures, please. Insert text directly

Comment: @grapes OK, right now

Comment: you should put the logs in the text not in picture